Maximising $\det(AQSS^TQ^TA^T)$ with respect to an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a diagonal scaling matrix $S$
I have a $y \times u$ matrix $A$, a $u \times u$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ and a $u \times u$  diagonal scaling matrix $S = \mathrm{diag}(s_1, \dots, s_u)$, where $y < u$.
Given $A$, I want to find the $Q$ and $S$ that maximise $\det(AQSS^TQ^TA^T)$, subject to the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^u s_i^2 = p$. (In the product QS, S effectively scales the columns of Q.)
Is there a closed form solution to this?

The determinant is multiplicative so $det(AQS) = det(A)det(Q)det(S)$. So you can just maximize the determinants independently.

there is something wrong with your dimensions -- if either $y=u$ or the matrix $(AQS)$ is not square and the determinant does not exist

@user8675309 thank you for pointing out this mistake - I have amended the question

Since $\det(AQS^2Q^TA^T)=\det\left(A(QM)(M^TSM)^2(M^TQ^T)A^T\right)$ for any permutation matrix $M$, we may assume that $s_1^2\ge s_2^2\ge\cdots\ge s_u^2$.
Let $A=PU^T$ be a polar decomposition where $U^T$ has orthonormal rows. Then $W^T=U^TQ$ has orthonormal rows too, and $\det(AQS^2Q^TA^T)=\det(P)^2\det(W^TS^2W)$. Let $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge \lambda_y\,(\ge0)$ be the eigenvalues of $W^TS^2W$ arranged in descending order. By the variational characterisation of eigenvalues of real symmetric matrices, we have $s_i^2\ge \lambda_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,y$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\det(AQS^2Q^TA^T)
&\le\det(P)^2\prod_{i=1}^ys_i^2\\
&\le\det(P)^2\left(\frac1y\sum_{i=1}^ys_i^2\right)^y\\
&\le\det(P)^2\left(\frac py\right)^y\\
&=\det(AA^T)\left(\frac py\right)^y.\\
\end{align*}
Equalities hold when $s_i=\pm\sqrt{\frac{p}{y}}$ for all $i\le y$, $s_i=0$ for all $i>y$ and $W^T=\pmatrix{I_y&0}$. This means the corresponding optimiser $Q$ is given by any orthogonal matrix whose first $y$ columns are those from $U$.

regarding the relationship between your answer to this question and your answer to a related question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937334/maximising-detab-with-respect-to-b), am I right in thinking that if $p=y$ and each $s_i$ is positive, then the optimal $QS$ in this question equals $\tilde{B} = [B, 0]$, where I have concatenated an extra $u-y$ columns of zeros to the optimal $B$ from the other question?

@Jabby If by ‘the optimal $B$ from the other question’ (note that the optimal solution to the linked question is only unique up to a right multiplication of orthogonal matrix), you mean $B=U$ where $U$ comes from the polar decomposition $A=PU^T$, yes.
